# I kept getting the error “ Case statement must cover all possible values of expression”. How do I fix this?

Tags: vhdl, quartus

[Part one of vhdl code for simon game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBXnV.png)

[Part two of vhdl code for simon game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbRqP.png)

[Part three of vhdl code for simon game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVpgA.png)

I got the case statement must cover all possible values of expression at line 35, "Case display counter is"

[This is what I'm trying to accomplish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psA32.jpg)

Please let me know if you see any other errors in the code.

Here is the typed version of the code below

```
library IEEE;

use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;

use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

entity SimonGame is

Port ( clk : in STD_LOGIC;

       rst : in STD_LOGIC;

       btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4 : in STD_LOGIC;

       hex_0, hex_1, hex_2 : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(6 downto 0));

end SimonGame;


architecture Behavioral of SimonGame is

signal sequence : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(2 downto 0);

signal count : INTEGER := 0;

signal display_counter : INTEGER := 0;

signal correct_input : BOOLEAN := TRUE;

type Digit_State is (DISPLAY_SEQUENCE, AWAIT_INPUT);

signal state : Digit_State := DISPLAY_SEQUENCE;

begin
process(clk, rst)
begin
    if rst = '1' then
        sequence <= "001"; -- Initial sequence
        count <= 0;
        display_counter <= 0;
        state <= DISPLAY_SEQUENCE;
    elsif rising_edge(clk) then
        case state is
            when DISPLAY_SEQUENCE =>
                -- Display the sequence on hex_0 and hex_1
                case display_counter is
                    when 0 =>
                        hex_0 <= "0000001";
                        hex_1 <= "0000000";
                    when 1 =>
                        hex_0 <= "0001000";
                        hex_1 <= "0000000";
                    when 2 =>
                        hex_0 <= "0000100";
                        hex_1 <= "0000000";
                    when 3 =>
                        hex_0 <= "0000010";
                        hex_1 <= "0000000";
                    when 4 =>
                        hex_0 <= "0001000";
                        hex_1 <= "0000000";
                    when 5 =>
                        hex_0 <= "0000001";
                        hex_1 <= "0000000";
                        state <= AWAIT_INPUT;
                end case;

                if display_counter < 5 then
                    display_counter <= display_counter + 1;
                else
                    display_counter <= 0;
                    count <= count + 1;
                    sequence <= sequence(0) & sequence(2 downto 1); -- Shift the sequence
                end if;

            when AWAIT_INPUT =>
                -- Check button input against the sequence
                if btn1 = '1' then
                    correct_input <= (sequence = "001");
                elsif btn4 = '1' then
                    correct_input <= (sequence = "010");
                elsif btn3 = '1' then
                    correct_input <= (sequence = "100");
                elsif btn2 = '1' then
                    correct_input <= (sequence = "010");
                else
                    correct_input <= FALSE;
                end if;

                if correct_input then
                    state <= DISPLAY_SEQUENCE;
                end if;
        end case;
    end if;
end process;
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Please post code as text, not images of text.  What makes you disagree with the error?

Comment: Besides Ada's answer adding an others choice (which stands for any value not previously a choice alternative) you could constraint the range `signal display_counter : INTEGER range 0 to 5 := 0;` wherein the case statement would then cover all values. And here the initial value would redundant, the default would be the left value of the range.

Answer (score 1):

A `case` statement must always cover all possible values that your variable can take. In your case 0 <= `display_counter` <= 5 is covered, but what if `display_counter` is smaller than 0 or larger than 5? You have to tell your program what to do in these cases. The general structure looks like this:

```vhdl
case my_variable is
    when value1 =>
        -- do something for value1
    when value2 =>
        -- do something for value2
    when others =>
        -- default action when my_variable doesn't match any defined case
end case;
```

So I think your problem will be resolved if you add `when others` with a corresponding action. Not doing anything is also a valid action, that could look something like this:

```vhdl
when others =>
        null;
```

Comment: There's also constraining display_counter which is an integer to a range of 0 to 5.  The sequence of statements in a case statement alternative can be empty ( sequence_of_statements ::= { sequential_statement }  "Braces { } enclose a repeated item or items on the right-hand side of a production. The items may
appear zero or more times;" )  "The execution of the null statement has no effect other than to pass on to the next statement."